# Not able to get the Threadlocal value

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I am trying to print numbers 0,1, 2 and so on using the three different threads in below order by using threadlocal variables :

```
0- thread 0
1- Thread 1
2- Thread 2
3- thread 0
4- Thread 1
.
.
```

Below is the code where i am putting an integer in the threadlocal storage and comparing it with the atomic integer which gets incremented by every thread.

```
  public class alternate123 
{

public static void main(String as[])
{  
    Object ob = new Object ();AtomicInteger t = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Thread t1 = new Thread ( new printpattern(t,0),"t0");
    Thread t2 = new Thread ( new printpattern(t,1),"t1");
    Thread t3 = new Thread ( new printpattern(t,2),"t2" );

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();



}

}
class printpattern implements Runnable
{
    //Integer t ;
    //Object ob = new Object ();
    AtomicInteger ai;
    private  ThreadLocal<Integer> t = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() ;
    public printpattern(AtomicInteger at,Integer i)
    {
        //
        ai=at;
        t.set(i);
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        synchronized (ai) { 
        while (true)
        {if (ai.get()%3==
            t.get()) // ----------------------- null pointer exception here 
            {
                try {
                    ai.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Current thread id "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"value of integer is "+ai.get());;
            ai.incrementAndGet();
            ai.notify();
        }
    }
    }

}
```

i am getting null while trying to do t.get() and below is the stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "t2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at printpattern.run(alternate123.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Exception in thread "t0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at printpattern.run(alternate123.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Exception in thread "t1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at printpattern.run(alternate123.java:46)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

i am setting threadlocal variable using set method which i doubt is erroneous . Please let me know what could be the issue .

Comment: `oddeven.t` is not defined in your example...

Comment: @Betlista : corrected now :)

Answer (score 4):

The constructor is called in your main thread, so the value is set for that thread: you have to set the threadlocal value in the run method. Just store the integer value (i param in your constructor) as a field inside printpattern class and then call t.set(i) in the run method.

P.S.: please rename printpattern to PrintPattern - it's a class.

Answer (score 1):

**Calling the `set` method will only assign the value for the current threa**d. You are setting the value from your main thread. So it will only be available from your main thread.

Actually, **you only need 1 instance of a `ThreadLocal`** in this case, then you can reuse it for multiple threads. But either way, it is crucial that you set the value from within the individual threads. (i.e. in your `run` method)

You could see a `ThreadLocal<Integer>` object as a `Map<Thread, Integer>` in a way, where the set method is equivalent to `map.put(Thread.currentThread(), value)`. That's not really how it works internally, but from a functional point of view, that's pretty much what it does.

Here's **an example that reuses the threadlocal** for multiple threads. (Changes are marked with `//CHANGE x` comments.)

```
public class Alternate123 {

    public static void main(String as[]) {
        // CHANGE 1: create only 1 threadlocal instance.
        ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();

        // CHANGE 2: pass the threadlocal to the individual threads.
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new printpattern(0, threadLocal), "t0");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new printpattern(1, threadLocal), "t1");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new printpattern(2, threadLocal), "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

}

class printpattern implements Runnable {
    // CHANGE 3: keep track of the initial value
    Integer startValue;
    ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocal;

    AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

    public printpattern(Integer i, ThreadLocal<Integer> threadLocal) {
        // CHANGE 4: don't assign the value to the threadlocal yet.
        // Because we are still in the main-thread when we reach this point.
        this.startValue = i;
        this.threadLocal = threadLocal;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // CHANGE 5: Assign the initial value to the threadlocal
        // this time we are doing it from within the individual threads.
        if (this.threadLocal.get() == null) {
            this.threadLocal.set(startValue);
        }

        synchronized (ai) {
            while (true) {
                if (ai.get() % 3 == t.get()) {
                    try {
                        ai.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // CHANGE 6: I had to change something here to make it compile. Not really relevant.
                System.out.println("Current thread id " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "value of integer is ...");

                ai.incrementAndGet();
                ai.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```